# Not able to push my-fix-branch to linkedin/wherehows.git

Tags: github

I am trying to push my branch to linkedin github repo using the command git push origin my-fix-branch.
And error I am getting is *remote: Permission to linkedin/WhereHows.git denied to .
fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/linkedin/WhereHows.git/': The reques
ted URL returned error: 403*

Comment: Are you trying to directly push to their repo? You cannot do that! Fork the project and raise a Pull Request.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot push to a repo without push permissions. You do not have push permissions to the linkedin repositories:

> remote: Permission to linkedin/WhereHows.git denied to username

What should you do:

1. Fork the repository
2. Create local commits
3. Push to the **forked** repository
4. Create pull request from your forked repository to the origin

Here is the official documentation: [Fork A Repo](https://help.github.com/articles/fork-a-repo/)